# jQuery removing a previous set class or removing with wildcard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JS which sets a background class. However, is it possible to remove the previous set class?

I cannot remove them all as it contains other classes so just whatever is set from that on mouseover function or maybe if that's not possible removing wildcard class?

Classes being set all end with *-bean-bags so maybe we could do that but guess not that flexible.

Whats expected:

- Hover item and set class
- Hover another item and remove previous set class and set new class

Anyone have any ideas?

```
$('.ty-menu__submenu-list li').on("mouseover", function () {
            var menuBackground = $(this).attr("data-background");
            //console.log(menuBackground);
            $("div.ty-menu__submenu.ty-menu__submenu-to-right").removeClass (function (index, css) {
                return (css.match (/\b-bean-bags\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
            });
            $("div.ty-menu__submenu.ty-menu__submenu-to-right").addClass(menuBackground);
        });
```

Comment: you want to only remove classes that end with `-bean-bags`?

Comment: yes, but if any of the menu names change it would not then work so i think woud  be better and if its possible to store the last class set and then remove when adding the new one? is that possible?

Comment: sorry dude but i dont understand your sentences. please make an example of the desired behaviour

Comment: So when i hover a menu item, it takes the class set in data-background and adds the class to  parent div container so i can then set a background image however when i ontinue to hover other menu items it adds their classes but i need to remove the previous one before setting the new one. does that make sense?

Comment: not quite. edit your question and provide before/ after markup of what you want please

Comment: I adjusted with bullet points, just need to remove previous class set before adding the new one thats all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the class to remove in a custom attribute, like this:

```
$('.ty-menu__submenu-list li').on("mouseover", function () {

    //Get the names of the new class
    var menuNewBackground = $(this).attr("data-background");

    //Get a reference to the element with the classes.
    elm = $("div.ty-menu__submenu.ty-menu__submenu-to-right");

    //Get the name of the old class
    var menuOldBackground = elm.attr("data-background-old");

    //First remove the old, add the new, and save the name of the new,
    //so that it can be used to remove it later.
    elm.removeClass(menuOldBackground)
       .addClass(menuNewBackground)
       .attr("data-background-old", menuNewBackground);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the same time that you add the class to the parent div, add the same value to a `data-prev-class` (or whatever you wish to call it) attribute of the parent div.  With it being in two places, you will be able to access it from a more variable like way.

Comment: Ahh think i understand ill give that a go.

Comment: I done: $("div.ty-menu__submenu.ty-menu__submenu-to-right").attr("data-prev-class",menuBackground);
   var prevClass = $("div.ty-menu__submenu.ty-menu__submenu-to-right").attr("data-prev-class");
   $("div.ty-menu__submenu.ty-menu__submenu-to-right").removeClass(prevClass); but its not removing the class.. any ideas?